# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

If anyone is currently facing any issues when trying to update their current version of "Android Studio" from, which ever version they are currently running to version 4.1 and they get the error below

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:295)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:238)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To solve this issue do the following as suggested by the following issue tracker

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-5051

1. Locate the following directory on the specific OS that you use :

   **MacOS**:
   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1

   **Linux**:
   ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1

   **Windows**:
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
2. Delete that directory; and
3. Now run android studio (do not reinstall run the new installation that you installed) , .

Comment: @Arun please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: On my PopOS install it was in: `~/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio` directory